# How to properly declare a php function as a variable in another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm looking to display a piece of javascript after the 6th paragraph of every post on my wordpress blog. So far, I can only get the function to work when I'm using a fixed variable:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) { 
    $ad_code = 'fixed variable such as <div>box</div>';

    if (is_single()) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 6, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

The javascript I'm trying to add:

```
function ad_unit() ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ad = document.getElementById('marker');
        if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width;  
        } else {
            adWidth = ad.offsetWidth; // for old IE 
        }
        /* Choose the right ID */
        if ( adWidth >= 600 )
          aId = ["test1"];  
        else if ( adWidth >= 468 )
          aId = ["test2"]; 
        else
          aId = ["test3"]; 
        document.write (
            '<div id="' + akId[0] + '"></div>'
        );
    </script>
<?php
```

I've tried to declare $placeholder = ad_unit(); but it keep displaying the unit at the top of the content instead of after the 6th paragraph. Somehow the prefix_insert_after paragraph function doesn't work after I add the javascript function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with [`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/ob_start) and [`ob_get_clean()`](https://www.php.net/ob_get_clean)

```
function ad_unit() 
{ 
    ob_start();

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      ad = document.getElementById('marker');
      if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width;  
      } else {
        adWidth = ad.offsetWidth; // for old IE 
      }
      /* Choose the right ID */
      if ( adWidth >= 600 )
        aId = ["test1"];  
      else if ( adWidth >= 468 )
        aId = ["test2"]; 
      else
        aId = ["test3"]; 
      document.write ('<div id="' + akId[0] + '"></div>');
    </script>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

So what happens is that with `ob_start()` you enable output buffering. You output the HTML but buffer it, then with `ob_get_clean()` you get the buffered output from the output buffer.

This will be cleaner without a function (and definitely work, I don't remember what plain HTML does when put in a PHP function):

```
// Somewhere above the rest of your application
ob_start(); ?>

/// YOUR HTML/javascript

<?php
$advertisement = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: output buffers are really great, you can capture what would get sent to the browser w/o it, instead save the buffer into a variable

Comment: WOOT. Thanks man! That did the trick. I wasn't aware how useful `ob_start();` and `ob_get _clean();` are. I read a little bit on PHP.net but damn it's really confusing.

By the way, is this a better way of calling hardcoded html/js then simply closing the php tags to include html/js?

Comment: Sometimes stuff you put in functions are not supposed to be shown where you call the function. Using the output buffer guarantees this. Even if you are absolutely 100% sure that the function will only be called where the output is supposed to be, use the output buffer. Plans change. This might be an interesting read: http://web.archive.org/web/20101216035343/http://dev-tips.com/featured/output-buffering-for-web-developers-a-beginners-guide

Answer (score 0):

You need opening and closing brackets for the php function

```
    <?php
    function ad_unit() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ad = document.getElementById('marker');
        if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width;  
        } else {
            adWidth = ad.offsetWidth; // for old IE 
        }
        /* Choose the right ID */
        if ( adWidth >= 600 )
          aId = ["test1"];  
        else if ( adWidth >= 468 )
          aId = ["test2"]; 
        else
          aId = ["test3"]; 
        document.write (
            '<div id="' + akId[0] + '"></div>'
        );
    </script>
    <?php }
```

Comment: In the code you posted you were missing open and closing brackets, so unless the function `ad_unit` goes on beyond the line:`<?php` and you have a closing bracket for it after that line than you are missing the closing bracket as well